# A function declared to return int returns nothing. Is this Undefined Behavior?

Tags: c++, function, undefined-behavior

This is a valid function in C++:

```
int f()
{
   if(false)
   {
      return 42;
   }
}
```

The following definition causes UB:

```
int x = f(); // return value used
```

**The question:**
Does the following expression statement cause UB?

```
f();
```

Quote from the standard would be very much welcome.

Comment: I'm 99.9999 % sure it's an UB. And even if it is not, this is not a programming style one would recommend :)

Comment: Trying to execute code in a comment is not UB.

Comment: i like how C# compiler handles it: in this case there will be compilation error: "Not all code paths return a value"

Comment: @Hans Passant if it is not UB you say, then it is defined? and how is it defined?

Comment: @dark_charlie: See the updated warning :)))

Comment: Since I seem to be the only one on the out, what does "UB" mean?

Comment: @AndyPerfect undefined behavior

Comment: // return value used.  It isn't used, the code optimizer removes the assignment statement.

Comment: Why don't you compile with -Wall -Werror? It will afford you the luxury of not having to know answers to questions like this.

Comment: @Whoever: Someone voted to close this question because it is too localized :D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

C++03 §6.6.3/2:

Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a return with no value; this results in undefined behavior in a value-returning function.

So this is an UB in a function itself.

BTW gcc gives you a nice warning pointing to this UB:

```
In function 'int f()':
Line 7: warning: control reaches end of non-void function
```

Comment: the only answer (out of 4) that really says what was asked.

Comment: @Armen Tsirunyan: So precise timing =)

Comment: So is it really undefined behavior? Or just undefined behavior that the program ends up ignoring anyway, making the overall program determined?

Answer (score 3):

C++03, §6.6.3/2: "Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a return with no value; this results in undefined behavior in a value-returning function."

Note that the same is not true in C.

Comment: Hmm.. interesting. Thanks for the answer. SO in C only the first case is UB?

Comment: @Lazer: You have to use the value. `f();` alone is fine.

Comment: @Armen: Yes -- C99 §6.9.1/12: "If the } that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by the caller, the behavior is undefined."